# How to print tweets from twitter by a known access token?

Tags: python, twitter

```
from rauth.service import OAuth1Service

class TwitterClient:

    KNOWN_USERS = ['177512438-pJTdMgOPLJ8hCQFfDbPmkU3LRcCSHZd5VqoM3WaY', '7Z50XjV1CqDF1753Rzd4MkzSYN1oCY2FaaFtAZU']

    def __init__(self):
        # Get a real consumer key & secret from https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
        self.twitter = OAuth1Service(
            name='twitter',
            consumer_key='ZjXNoqpLfhQvYBgkjrrvxQ',
            consumer_secret='8O4NjcsNed8uGICjDLNTjPiNwqjPezovWZIVru1c',
            request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
            authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
            base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1/')
        #self.KNOWN_USERS = ['177512438-pJTdMgOPLJ8hCQFfDbPmkU3LRcCSHZd5VqoM3WaY', '7Z50XjV1CqDF1753Rzd4MkzSYN1oCY2FaaFtAZU']

    def new_session(self):
        request_token, request_token_secret = self.twitter.get_request_token()
        authorize_url = self.twitter.get_authorize_url(request_token)
        print 'Visit this URL in your browser: ' + authorize_url
        pin = raw_input('Enter PIN from browser: ')
        session = self.twitter.get_auth_session(request_token,
                                                request_token_secret,
                                                method='POST',
                                                data={'oauth_verifier': pin})
        print session.access_token, session.access_token_secret # Save this to database
        return session

    def reuse_session(self, user2):
        access_token = user2[0]
    access_token_secret = user2[1]
        session = self.twitter.get_session((access_token, access_token_secret))
        return session

    def init_session(self, user2):
        if user2[0] == self.KNOWN_USERS[0] and user2[1] == self.KNOWN_USERS[1] : session = self.reuse_session(user2)
        else                        : session = self.new_session()
        return session

    def list_tweets(self, user2):
        session = self.init_session(user2)
        params = {'include_rts': 1,  # Include retweets
                  'count': 10}       # 10 tweets

        r = session.get('statuses/home_timeline.json', params=params)

        for i, tweet in enumerate(r.json(), 1):
            handle = tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
            text = tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')
            print '{0}. @{1} - {2}'.format(i, handle, text)

    tc = TwitterClient()

    user1 = ['177512438-pJTdMgOPLJ8hCQFfDbPmkU3LRcCSHZd5VqoM3WaY', '7Z50XjV1CqDF1753Rzd4MkzSYN1oCY2FaaFtAZU']
    tc.list_tweets( user1 )
```

But this gives the following error in line 50:

```
string indices must be integer
```

So instead I write this:

```
from rauth.service import OAuth1Service

class TwitterClient:

    KNOWN_USERS = { # (access_token, access_token_secret)
        'user1' : ('177512438-pJTdMgOPLJ8hCQFfDbPmkU3LRcCSHZd5VqoM3WaY', '7Z50XjV1CqDF1753Rzd4MkzSYN1oCY2FaaFtAZU')
    }

    def __init__(self):
        # Get a real consumer key & secret from https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new
        self.twitter = OAuth1Service(
            name='twitter',
            consumer_key='ZjXNoqpLfhQvYBgkjrrvxQ',
            consumer_secret='8O4NjcsNed8uGICjDLNTjPiNwqjPezovWZIVru1c',
            request_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
            access_token_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
            authorize_url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
            base_url='https://api.twitter.com/1.1/')

    def new_session(self):
        request_token, request_token_secret = self.twitter.get_request_token()
        authorize_url = self.twitter.get_authorize_url(request_token)
        print 'Visit this URL in your browser: ' + authorize_url
        pin = raw_input('Enter PIN from browser: ')
        session = self.twitter.get_auth_session(request_token,
                                                request_token_secret,
                                                method='POST',
                                                data={'oauth_verifier': pin})
        print session.access_token, session.access_token_secret # Save this to database
        return session

    def reuse_session(self, user1):
        access_token, access_token_secret = self.KNOWN_USERS[user1]
        session = self.twitter.get_session((access_token, access_token_secret))
        return session

    def init_session(self, user1):
        if user1 in self.KNOWN_USERS : session = self.reuse_session(user1)
        else                        : session = self.new_session()
        return session

    def list_tweets(self, user1):
        session = self.reuse_session(user1)
        params = {'include_rts': 1,  # Include retweets
                  'count': 10}       # 10 tweets

        r = session.get('statuses/home_timeline.json', params=params)
    print r.json
        #for i, tweet in enumerate(r.json(), 1):
            #handle = tweet['user']['screen_name'].encode('utf-8')
            #text = tweet['text'].encode('utf-8')
            #print '{0}.  - {2}'.format(i, text)

tc = TwitterClient()

tc.list_tweets('user1')
```

But I get the following error:

```
<bound method Response.json of <Response [401]>>
```

Comment: Presumably you're indexing into a string as though it were a dictionary. Can you give us the traceback?

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal information you've given us, I'm guessing your GET request is failing, causing you to receive a JSON object that looks like this:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

This will decode as a dictionary, and when you iterate over it you'll get the keys in the dictionary, which are strings. When you attempt to index into those strings using dictionary keys, you'll get the error that you can only index into strings (or any sequences) using integers.

Verify this by printing r.json() before iterating over it. Fix it by reading the error message you're getting back and remedying the problem it's reporting to you.

Comment: printing r.json gives this error   <bound method Response.json of <Response [401]>>

Comment: Don't print r.json, the object. Call r.json() and print the result.